# SSL certificate does not update

Tags: nginx, docker, ssl-certificate

My previous SSL certificate just expired.

[image]

I tried to buy another free SSL certificate from AliCloud and also sslforfree.com. I'm pretty sure I have already installed a right certificate in the server. But when I test it in my Mac ([www.10studio.tech](http://www.10studio.tech)), it always shows the old certificate.

Clearing browsing history does not help.

Could anyone confirm me that it is not working just for me? And what could I do?

**Edit 1:**

I use docker and nginx. In nginx and sslforfree.com, I have the following `my_server_block.conf`.

```
server {
  listen  3002;
  absolute_redirect off;
  root  /app;

  location = / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/docs/introduction redirect;
  }
    
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}

server {
  listen  3001 ssl;

  ssl_certificate      /certs/whole.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /certs/private.key;

  ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
  }
}
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  docusaurus:
    image: bitnami/nginx:1.16
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./build:/app
    - ./certs:/certs:ro
    - ./my_server_block.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/my_server_block.conf:ro
    ports:
    - "3001:3001"
    - "3002:3002"
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
# Based on https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/#nginx-conf
# user              www www;  ## Default: nobody

worker_processes  auto;
error_log         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log";
pid               "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/nginx.pid";

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format    main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status  $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log    "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log";
    add_header    X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

    client_body_temp_path  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body" 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/proxy" 1 2;
    fastcgi_temp_path      "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/fastcgi" 1 2;
    scgi_temp_path         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/scgi" 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/uwsgi" 1 2;

    sendfile           on;
    tcp_nopush         on;
    tcp_nodelay        off;
    gzip               on;
    gzip_http_version  1.0;
    gzip_comp_level    2;
    gzip_proxied       any;
    gzip_types         text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    ssl_protocols      TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/*.conf";

    # HTTP Server
    server {
        # port to listen on. Can also be set to an IP:PORT
        listen  8080;

        location /status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log   off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your certificate is showing as expired according to SSL Labs. Can you share your configuration?

Comment: By the way, this isn't directly relevant to your problem, but the report also showed that your server is configured to accept connections using both TLS 1.0 and 1.1, both of which should be deprecated.

Comment: Where's your Docker configuration? Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, whatever?

Comment: I just added `docker-compose.yml`; there is no `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I think you need to re`build` this. Your nginx is reporting version 1.9.4, which is quite old and not at all the 1.16 you've requested.

Comment: How did you see my nginx is `1.9.4`?

Comment: I just looked at the response headers.

Comment: I just added `nginx.conf`. How could I `rebuild` all this?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing is you have to reload/restart your web server after updating the TLS certificate.

It looks like you're using docker-compose, but your containers don't seem to have been updated, as your nginx version reports 1.9.4 while you seem to have asked for 1.16.x. Consider force updating with something like:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate --build -d
```

Comment: I did... I use docker, and I restarted the container, nginx... everything...

Comment: I added some note...

Comment: I just tried `docker-compose up --force-recreate --build -d`, it did not help...

Comment: @SoftTimur At this point I think there is some important detail that is missing. We don't have any way to know what that is. Please think about your set up and describe any part of it that you might not have mentioned before.

Comment: Don't you think it is because we did not clear the old SSL certificate on our machine properly?

Comment: @SoftTimur I have no idea. That is one of the things you have not yet described.

Comment: I wrote `clearing browsing history does not help`... By the way, `image: bitnami/nginx:1.16` is the version of the image, rather than the version of nginx...

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the certificates in that location are the correct certificates.  Assuming you have correctly restarted nginx, and there is no other configuration overwriting the one you provided, nginx must be loading the certificates at that location.  Perhaps you placed the certificates in that directory on the host machine rather than in that directory within the Docker image?